# Error with ReadPreference using Mongos in node-mongodb.native

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm having an issue with GridFS while using MongoS for node-mongodb-native.  I opened an issue in github, but it's really just a symptom of the problem.  The error that doesn't get caught complains about ReadPreference not being set.  I can't find a good example of setting ReadPreference with GridFS.  Has anyone used the mongo driver in a sharded setup?

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/686

Comment: It was a bug and they pushed an update this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/686

They fixed this in the 1.1.5 driver update.